# Get a teamspeak server status in PHP

Tags: php, voip, status

I have a teamspeak server and I would like to show the server status (online, offline) in a webpage (in PHP). Could you help me please ? I tried different things, but it doesn't works.

Thanks !!

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried?

Comment: fsockopen + fread should work, be sure to use a timeout below 1 second to not cause endless load times, try to cache the result for a few seconds or even longer http://php.net/fsockopen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Teamspeak 3 then this can be done pretty easily by using the Teamspeak php framework. (http://addons.teamspeak.com/directory/tools/integration/TeamSpeak-3-PHP-Framework.html)

After that you can use something along this to check the status of your server:

```
TeamSpeak3::init();
$status = "offline";
$ts3 = TeamSpeak3::factory("serverquery://<queryusername>:<password>@<name_or_ip>:<queryport>/?server_port=<ts3port>&use_offline_as_virtual=1&no_query_clients=1");
$status = $ts3->getProperty("virtualserver_status");
```

You could also use the isOnline function of the Teamspeak3_node_server.

Comment: For what is the `$status = "offline";`? I don't see the reason for that.

Comment: @Shuro It's for initializing it to a default status. So that it says its offline even if the TeamSpeak3::Factory fails.

Comment: better use try-catch